# "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" exclusively in my browser (Docker)

Tags: angular, docker, browser, containers

for a project I need to contenerize an angular project. I am using Docker

When I run my container, inside the container, I can curl the http://localhost4200. However, when I want to see in my browser the response, here is the response : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
What did I try ?

- I tried to change the ip bind 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1.
- I verified that I had nothing on my port that I am mapping.

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:latest

EXPOSE 4200 8080

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y sudo \
    default-jdk \ 
    curl \
    software-properties-common \
    wget \ 
    zip \
    whois \
    nano

COPY entrypoint.sh /bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD /bin/bash /bin/entrypoint.sh
```

Here is my Dockercompose :

```
version: '3'
services:      
    angular-app:
       build: project
       tty: true
       ports:
           - "8081:4200"
           - "8082:8080"
```

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

I resolved the problem. I missunderunstood that I had to change on my container the local adress. I changed it to 0.0.0.0 and then it worked.

Comment: You need to access `http://localhost8081`

Comment: I already tried it. Instead. I mapped the port 4200 with the port 8081 (on my host). I can curl in my container http://localhost:4200. But in my browser (on my host), I can't curl http://localhost:8081.

Comment: The response with http://localhost:8081 is now "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: You can curl because your app is listening on port 4200, but you see empty response because probably your app does have nothing to show. Run `docker logs container_name` to see the logs

Comment: In my script entrypoint.sh, I create my project and run  the Angular Server. So in my opinion, there is something to show. When I look at the logs, I see that my Angular app is running and compiled successfully

Comment: can you share what `entrypoint.sh` looks like?